# RecyclerView+GridLayoutManager make item span multiple rows

Tags: java, android

I have a collection of photos, and I'm using a RecyclerView to display them. I want to have the first element in my RecyclerView span 2 columns AND 2 rows: 
[image]

I know I can span 2 columns with setSpanSizeLookup:

```
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

**but how can I also make the first item span 2 rows as well?? ,, if i cant do that with GridLayoutManager  then ,How can i do it ,What should i use ?**

Comment: With the default implementation of `GridLayoutManager` you can't span both vertically and horizontally at the same time

Comment: OK, How can i do that , what should i use ?

Comment: Not sure if StaggeredGridLayoutManager allow you to do that

Comment: [Here](https://enoent.fr/blog/2015/01/18/recyclerview-basics/) there is a tutorial which uses `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` but this class has not been created for this specific use case. It has been created for "pushing" some views in the next rows setting the gap strategy. Btw you can try and see if with some modifications  you are able to reach the same thing, or maybe trying the library @Robillo suggested which looks promising

Comment: @MatPag i have tons of code that has been  built of the Grid layout manger and the link you sent have a lot of adapter modifications and that means time and the end result is zero granted on image-video play in realtime, i will try the lib post by Robillo first and try this if that lib dos not work or it very laggy or some weird issue

Comment: @iMyth the best choice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Within the Android framework you cannot directly perform this operation without writing custom code. **But** check out this library, it does things similar to what you want to achieve. Here's the link: https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager

Comment: i will try it,, give some moment